# Cant set tables width to 100% unless table-layout: fixed, but then, table cell widths are fixed

Tags: html, css

I have a table inside an article tag. I want the table to be 100% wide. When the article goes narrow, the table should shrink.

That works when the table has the css property `table-layout: fixed`.
The problem is that then, the table cells are not any longer adapting their widths to their content.

Is it impossible to get both?

Cases:

- 1. table-layout is fixed
     [image: fixed table layout]
     The table adjusts its width to the parent width, but cells have the same width regardless of contents.
     Code: https://jsfiddle.net/7yLswLg9/14/ .
     Fullscreen: https://jsfiddle.net/7yLswLg9/14/embedded/result/
- 2. table-layout is not fixed
     [image]
     The table does not adjust its width to the parent. The cells adapts the widths to the contents.
     Code: https://jsfiddle.net/7yLswLg9/13/
     Fullscreen: https://jsfiddle.net/7yLswLg9/13/embedded/result/

Wished scenario: The cell widths adapts to content and the table width adapts to the parent, scaling if needed.

Comment: How could the browser handle the desired behaviour when the cells content is images?

Comment: By scaling them was thea idea...

Comment: Something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/7yLswLg9/16/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you were simply missing the "display: block" property on each img in your fiddle.

Take a look at this one ( moved the img styling to a class called "img-responsive" )

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7yLswLg9/20/

Comment: The images height does not stretch in that jsfiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7yLswLg9/19/ -  All you need to do is change the height: auto to height: 100%

Comment: That destroys the aspect ratio.

Comment: You can't retain the aspect ratio when the container for each img is a table cell, and the table container is less than the combined width value of every image ...  it's like trying to fit the mona lisa in a circus clowns car

Comment: Hahaha, I do not agree, but I like how you describe it.

Comment: I want images to have the same height, side by side and the width of all images be a certain amount, scaling the height of the table as needed. In my head that works without making me think about clowns stealing artwork :)

Comment: @elad.chen I'm pretty sure the [Mona Lisa would fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mona_Lisa).  It's not that large ;)